# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException:Cannot deserialize thecurrentJSONobject (e.g.{"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Tags: c#, .net

I am facing an error in the above mentioned way. The code is as follows:

```
public virtual void Initialize()
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_projectName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("projectName");

            var uri = $"{CustomVisionEndpoint}/customvision/v3.0/training/projects";

            string responseContent;
            using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Add("Training-Key", _apiKey);
                var response = Client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
                responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }

            var projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Project>>(responseContent);

            var project = projects.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(_projectName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            
            if (project == null) throw new InvalidOperationException($"CustomVision client failed to initialize. ({_projectName} Not Found.)");
            this._projectId = project.Id;
        }
```

I am using the customvision's interface for object detection purpose and get the JSON file from that project. All the keys and endpoints are obtained from there. I am facing the error at this line:

```
var projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Project>>(responseContent);
```

How to handle this error?

Comment: Please attach your JSON response for reproduce purpose. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry I am entirely new to this area, can you guide me on how to get the JSON response from the variable 'responseContent'?

Comment: You an try to place a breapoint after `responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` Add `responseContent` into Watch window or hover to `responseContent` to check how is the JSON string look like. Or Probably you can try submitting the API with [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)